# Formula for the Monodromy Zeta Function

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

My question is about how one may prove the last formula in the picture below. The original algebraic geometry paper where this appears is [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.4917.pdf) but I don't think the broader context is needed.

[image]

Just to clarify some of the notation here, we have a continuous map $h:F \to F$ called the monodromy; it and its powers $h^k$ induces maps on cohomology. Thus, the Lefschetz number of $h^k$ is this $\Lambda(h^k)$ which is an alternating sum of the trace of operators $(h^k)*:H^q(F) \to H^q(F)$; I think we can take cohomology over $\mathbb{C}$. The notation used in the paper for these operators is $H^q(h^k)$.

Now, consider this formula (1). Inserting the Lefschetz number's definition, the exponent is

$$-\sum_{k \geq 1} \sum_{q \geq 0} (-1)^qtr H^q(H^k) \frac{t^k}{k} = \sum_{q \geq 0} (-1)^{q+1} \sum_{k \geq 1} tr H^q(h^k) \frac{t^k}{k}.$$

Split the exponential by $q$; the formula becomes

$$\prod_{q \geq 0}\exp\left(\sum_{k\geq 1} tr H^q(h^k) \frac{t^k}{k}\right)^{(-1)^{q+1}}$$

Each term of the product looks suspiciously like each term of the definition though there's a difference of $(-1)^q$ and $(-1)^{q+1}$.

So let's see if we can prove $\det(Id-tH^q(h^k))^{-1} = \exp\left(\sum_{k\geq 1} tr H^q(h^k) \frac{t^k}{k}\right)$ for each $q$.

For ease, let's just fix a $q$ and let $A=H^q(h)$. Then $A^k = H^q(h^k)$; thank goodness for functoriality. If we assume $A$ is diagonal and has eigenvalue $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_\ell$ (with possible repeats), then
$$\det(Id - tA)^{-1} = \prod^\ell_{j=1} \frac{1}{1-t\lambda_j} = \prod^\ell_{j=1} \left(\sum^\infty_{n=0} (\lambda_jt)^n \right).$$

Hopefully, this equals
$$\exp\left(\sum_{k\geq 1} tr A^k \frac{t^k}{k}\right) = \prod_{k \geq 1} \exp( tr A^k \frac{t^k}{k}) = \prod_{k \geq 1} \exp( tr A^k)^{\frac{t^k}{k}}.$$

The trace of $A^k$ is $\lambda^k_1+...+\lambda^k_\ell$ so $\exp( tr A^k) = \prod^\ell_j e^{\lambda^k_j}$. Hence, $\prod_{k \geq 1} \exp( tr A^k)^{\frac{t^k}{k}} = \prod_{k \geq 1} \prod^\ell_j \exp(\frac{1}{k}(t\lambda_j)^k)$.

Fixing $j$, the hope is now $\prod_{k \geq 1} \exp(\frac{1}{k}(t\lambda_j)^k) = \sum^\infty_{n=0} (\lambda_jt)^n$. But that doesn't seem correct. So I probably made some mistake and I can't help but feel this is a bad way to prove the correctness of the formula.

Answer (score 1):

I think I can prove this now. Let's substitute in the Lefschetz number in the exponential. The power becomes:

$-\sum_{m \geq 1} \sum_{q \geq 0} (-1)^qtr H_q(\phi^m) \frac{s^m}{m} = \sum_{q \geq 0} (-1)^{q+1} \sum_{m \geq 1} tr H_q(\phi^m) \frac{s^m}{m}.$

When we split the exponential by $q$; the formula becomes:

$\prod_{q \geq 0}\exp\left(\sum_{m\geq 1} tr H_q(\phi^m) \frac{s^m}{m}\right)^{(-1)^{q+1}}$

Each term of the product looks suspiciously like each term of the definition though there's a difference of $(-1)^q$ and $(-1)^{q+1}$. So let's see if we can prove $\det(Id-sH_q(\phi))^{-1} = \exp\left(\sum_{m\geq 1} tr H_q(\phi^m) \frac{s^m}{m}\right)$ for each $q$. The $-1$ on the LHS is very important. Without it, you would just have a characteristic polynomial and we wouldn't get higher powers of the monodromy.

For ease, let's just fix a $q$ and let $A=H_q(\phi)$. Then $A^m = H_q(\phi^m)$; thank goodness for functoriality. We may assume $A$ is diagonal (we're working over $\mathbb{C}$) and has eigenvalue $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_\ell$ (with possible repeats). Then, the LHS can be rewritten as $\det(Id-sA)^{-1} = \prod^k_j (1-s\lambda_j)^{-1}$.

Observe that the RHS can be rewritten as:

$\exp\left(\sum_{m\geq 1} tr A^m \frac{s^m}{m}\right) = \prod_{m \geq 1} \exp(\frac{s^m}{m} \sum^k_j \lambda^m_j) = \prod_{m \geq 1} \prod^k_j \exp(\frac{s^m}{m} \lambda^m_j) = \prod^k_j \prod_{m\geq 1} \exp((s\lambda_j)^m/m)$.

Hence, let's fix a $j$ and prove that $(1-s\lambda_j)^{-1} = \prod_{m\geq 1} \exp((s\lambda_j)^m/m)$. If we take the log of both sides, we have

$-\log(1-s\lambda_j) = \sum_{m \geq 1} \frac{(s\lambda_j)^m}{m}$.

Now recall, $-\frac{1}{\lambda_j} \log(1-s\lambda_j)=\int \frac{ds}{1-s\lambda_j} = \int \sum^\infty_{n=0} (s\lambda_j)^n = \sum^\infty_{n=0} \frac{\lambda^n_j s^{n+1}}{n+1}$.

So then, multiplying by $\lambda_j$, we see that $-\log(1-s\lambda_j) = \sum_{m \geq 1} \frac{(s\lambda_j)^m}{m}$ is true. This proves the formula.